# Call function form one javascript file to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function written in one javascript file with in a if statement in another file. I have the order in my html right as the second file is being called after the first file.

First.js

```
function barFunction() {
  //Do Something
}
```

second.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])

myApp.controller('app', function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $route){
 $scope.selectedGraph = function () {

    if ($scope.graphChoose === true){
        barFunction()
    }else {
    }
  }
})
```

html code

```
<script src="first.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="second.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, so what's the problem?

Comment: this should work fine, unless you have errors in second js file

Comment: look to the browsers developer tools console for any errors